# SmtpFailedRecipientException not thrown from SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage)

Tags: c#, .net, email

I am trying to send an email to a fake email address and get a SmtpFailedRecipientException, however when I send the email to a fake address on my company domain, no exception is thrown. I am developing in VS2015 with .NET 4.5.2 and running the console application on a Windows 7 environment.

This code works correctly and sends emails when the email addresses are valid, and it will even throw a SmtpFailedRecipientException when I try sending to an invalid gmail or hotmail address. It seems that the only time an exception isn't thrown is when I try to send to a fake address within my company domain. Our company uses Office365 and I get an 'Undeliverable' message in my inbox when I try to send to the fake address from my address.

Does anyone have an idea why this is happening? I suspect it might be a setting on the mail server, but I dont have access to the mail server to check and see. I also might just be missing something obvious and be making a rookie mistake.

```
// Initialize SMTP client
SmtpClient client = null;
try
{
    string from = "myEmailAddress@mycompany.com", to = "fakeEmailAddress@mycompany.com";

    // Build client
    client = new SmtpClient("mail.mycompany.com");
    client.Port = 25;
    client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;

    // Create message
    using (MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to)
    {
        Subject = "Test email to fake address",
        Body = "This email won't be sent"
    })
    {
        // Send message
        client.Send(message);
    }
}
catch (SmtpFailedRecipientException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"SmtpFailedRecipientException caught.{Environment.NewLine}{ex.ToString()}");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Exception caught.{Environment.NewLine}{ex.ToString()}");
}
```

Comment: That exception won't ever be caught here unless your mail server rejects your login attempt.  When you use an external mail server, the mail is not initiated/delivered immediately, it is put in the outgoing messaging queue of the mail server.  It could be processed in 1 second or in 40 minutes.  A metaphor would be putting a letter in a mailbox.  Once you drop it in, its up to the postal service to deliver the mail.  If they can't it comes back to your home address saying undeliverable.  Your exception would be thrown if you couldn't find a mailbox to drop your letter in.

Comment: So the only way to get the exception for incorrect addresses in my company domain is to provide login credentials for the SmtpClient, correct?

Comment: I actually could be wrong on this as a lot of examples show it as working, but I've always been under the impression that even if the SMTP server accepts it, its not delivered immediately.  if you try a malformed email address, do you get the exception?

Comment: I have tried with a malformed address and I get a FormatException instead of a SmtpFailedRecipientException. Why is it that when I send to xxx@gmail.com, I get the exception, but when I send to xxx@mycompany.com I don't get it? Are the xxx@gmail.com emails not queued up or are the xxx@mycompany.com queued differently?

Comment: I would imagine it has to do with GMail servers knowing who is in their own directory(ies) and do not know who is a valid recipient on your own company servers.  So, I gather the exception will work if you are sending within your own organization (gmail, mycompany.com) but not if sending outside of it